# git cherry-pick a range of commits to prevent history breakage

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick, tree-conflict

## Short description of problem

After a new developers group joined our project they initialized a new repo and copied (not merged!) **snapshot of master** into newly created repo. So in their branch old files lost history of commits which exist in `master`. After that they started typical git workflow with comitting, branching, merging updates from master etc. And now the problem is to merge their code into `master` or `dev` excluding first two commits and preserving our history (and preserving their history also would be good).

## Detailed problem description

So we have branches: `master`, `dev` and `funny_developers`.

Here is our branch structure:

```
I---A---B---C---D---Y...X      <--(master/dev)
            \!\      \
       I'---IABC--G--DY..Z     <--(funny_developers flow)
```

`I...C...X` - is our main flow of developement (`master` and `dev` branches are syncronized now)  with history of commits. This flow has no imports from `funny_developers` branches

`I'` - is a commit where `funny_developers` re-initilised a new repo with empty one (seems they made `git-init`?) .

`IABC` - very dirty commit, where `funny_developers` copy all files existing in `master` at the moment of commit `C` as **new files**. Not merge from `C`, just recreate project's file structure! So they dropped out all history of changes made during `master` branch evolution).

`G..Z` - is a bulk of commits where they made a lot of changes. During this flow they also had merged updates from master several times, had created their own branches, had merged them into `funny_developers` (sometimes with conflict resolution), etc.

So now I have problems with merging `G..Z` into `master` preserving our initial history of commits and their too (excluding `I'` and `IABC` commits).

## Question

**Could you advice me the best method (if exist) to grab their commits into `master` and preserve commit history excluding first two ones?**

## My experiments for saving Queen and Kingdom at once

I tried `git cherry-pick G..Z`. But they were coding in parallel branches and were doing a lot of merges into `funny_developers`. They resolved a lot of own-branches conflicts. It seems I need a lot of time to resolve them again if I decide to use this method.

I tried `git rebase --onto master IABC Z`, expecting it able to move branch buckets all within `G..Z` onto `master`. But I stucked with a bunch of conflicts related to commits which was a long time ago (even before 'funny_developers' was started). And I can not understand how they relate to actual rebase (may be it because they have reinitilized repo...).

Anyway if I find no solution preserving "both histories" I tend to make diff for all their work and provide it as single patch-commit for `master`.

Comment: Look into `git rebase -i`, rebase is exactly what you mean by "cherry-pick multiple commits". Feel free to make extra branches.

Comment: Are you saying they created actual real merge commits (in a git sense) after their initial copy import?

Comment: @U2EF1 - FYI cherry-pick learned how to pick ranges a couple of Git versions ago

Comment: @AndrewC, yes after dirty commit `IABC` they had updated their code base by merging (in git sense) from master and resolving conflicts in favor of `master` version. 

See the commit `DY` on the graph above

Comment: you might try `git replace` here to fudge the "IABC" commit

Comment: @AndrewC, thanks! This is the best solution I found at the momemnt.

Comment: The only problem I can not understand: how can I share replaces with origin repo (according to docs it is possible, but I can not understand how i must specify this). 

I tried: `git push origin refs/replace/replaced_commit_sha1`
and
`git push origin +refs/replace/replaced_commit_sha1:refs/remotes/origin/replace/replaced_commit_sha1
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/user/myrepo.git
 * [new branch]      refs/replace/replaced_commit_sha1 -> origin/replace/replaced_commit_sha1`

Strange messages and nothing happens on remote.

Comment: Try just  `git push origin refs/replace/*`